# Using DEigensystem with parametrized cuboid

Tags: symbolic, regions, eigenvalues

The following code where `Cuboid` has a predefined dimensions `{1, 1, 1}` works fine:

```
ℒ = -Laplacian[u[x, y, z], {x, y, z}];
ℬ = DirichletCondition[u[x, y, z] == 0, True];

DEigensystem[{ℒ, ℬ}, 
 u[x, y, z], {x, y, z} ∈ Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}], 1, 
 Method -> Normalized]
(* {{3 π^2}, {Sin[π x] Sin[π y] Sin[π z]}} *)
```

However, if dimensions are symbolic, `{W, H, L}`, there is no result:

```
DEigensystem[{ℒ, ℬ}, 
  u[x, y, z], {x, y, z} ∈ Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {W, H, L}], 1, 
  Method -> Normalized]
(* Unevaluated *)
```

Can `DEigensystem` be made to work with variable dimensions of the `Cuboid` to obtain the solution in the same way as with the separation of variables by hand?